# Password problems in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: login, password

Ubuntu keeps asking me for my password to log in to my account when I enter the correct password, it asks for it again and will not accept it. Id does tell me if it's incorrect when I enter wrong password, though. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

reboot the machine and while the grub loader menu appers choose it and edit it type e  then choose the kernel and press e to edit and just end of the line put 1 and press B to boot after getting into run level 1 change your password using passwd command